# Photo Posting in Twitter in iOS5

Tags: ios5, twitter

I am new one to twitter integration in iOS5.

I need to post photos in twitter coming from services.

I have searched many and also practiced sample tutorials on this.
I am getting only photo URL. I need to post photo.

Can anyone help me regarding this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just append the photo URL to the tweet

Comment: yeah i did it.but in twitter url is posting.my requirement is to post that photo as it is...help me regarding this.

Comment: so you need to download the image and then upload to twitter using `TWTweetComposeViewController` (`addImage` method)

Answer (score 0):

First you need to save the images and then you can post saved image to twitter

```
 self.shareImg.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Your Saved image"];

 if ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue] > 5.0) {
        // Create the view controller
        TWTweetComposeViewController *twitter = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"I created this photo http://%@", iTune];

        // Optional: set an image, url and initial text
        [twitter addImage:self.shareImg.image];

        [twitter setInitialText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"I created this photo using USC Project Trojan App:http://uslofphoto.com. Download http://%@", iTune]];

        // Show the controller
        [self presentModalViewController:twitter animated:YES];

        // Called when the tweet dialog has been closed
        twitter.completionHandler = ^(TWTweetComposeViewControllerResult result) 
        {
            NSString *title = @"Tweet Status";
            NSString *msg; 

            if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultCancelled)
                msg = @"Tweet compostion was canceled.";
            else if (result == TWTweetComposeViewControllerResultDone)
                msg = @"Tweet composition completed.";

            // Show alert to see how things went...
            UIAlertView* alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:title message:msg delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Okay" otherButtonTitles:nil];
            [alertView show];

            // Dismiss the controller
            [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        };
    }
```